# How to make a row of square graphs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a row with 5 square graphs. I'm currently doing this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 5)
#code to populate the graphs here
plt.show()
```

However, this gives me 5 graphs that are very skinny and tall rectangles. If i size them down into squares with the format subplots tool, then the image generated is mostly white space. How can I generate these graphs as squares in one row, without all the white space?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set the figure size:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20,5) # width, height

plt.subplot( 151 ) # a fig with 1 row, 5 columns, 1st graph
plt.plot( x,y )
plt.subplot( 152 ) # 2nd graph
plt.plot( ... )
# and similarly for the next ones

plt.show()
```

Comment: Setting the global figsize is not a good solution, it seems more aligned with the question to do it on a per figure basis, as in Graeme's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the shape of your figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(5, 1))
#code to populate the graphs here
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)
plt.show()
```